# gst-launch-1.0 not showing video while pipeline is playing

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, basler

I am trying to use a basler camera on an IMX8m-plus board.

The camera is detected as:

```
root@ucm-imx8m-plus:~# v4l2-ctl --list-devices
 ():
        /dev/v4l-subdev0

mxc-isi-cap (platform:32e00000.isi:cap_devic):
        /dev/video0

FSL Capture Media Device (platform:mxc-md):
        /dev/media0
```

And has the following capture modes:

```
root@ucm-imx8m-plus:~# v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture Multiplanar

        [0]: 'RGBP' (16-bit RGB 5-6-5)
        [1]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
        [2]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
        [3]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        [4]: 'YUV4' (32-bit A/XYUV 8-8-8-8)
        [5]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
        [6]: 'YM24' (Planar YUV 4:4:4 (N-C))
        [7]: 'XR24' (32-bit BGRX 8-8-8-8)
        [8]: 'AR24' (32-bit BGRA 8-8-8-8)
```

Starting `gst-launch-1.0` results in this output:

```
root@ucm-imx8m-plus:~# gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=320,height=240 ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(stri[ 2318.660751] bypass csc
ng)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)p[ 2318.665343] input fmt YUV4
rogressive, colorimetry=(string)1[ 2318.670921] output fmt YUYV
:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoRate:videorate0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstWaylandSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoRate:videorate0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, format=(string)YUY2, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:5:1
```

No video is showing while this is active.

The `videotestsrc` is working perfectly fine. And the camera is working on different systems as well.

```
root@ucm-imx8m-plus:~# gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRA, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRA, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstWaylandSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRA, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRA, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, multiview-mode=(string)mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

The system is an yocto-image (hardknott 5.10.72-2.2.0) from compulab.
What do I need to change and/or test to display the camera stream correctly?

Edits:

```
root@ucm-imx8m-plus:/opt/dart-bcon-mipi/lib# gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)120/1, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1
/GstPipeline[ 315.657117] bypass csc
:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0.[ 315.660021] input fmt YUV4
GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, [ 315.665603] output fmt YUYV
format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)120/1, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1


root@ucm-imx8m-plus:/opt/dart-bcon-mipi/lib# gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovid[ 362.197247] bypass csc
eosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxy[ 362.201367] input fmt YUV4
Pad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-raw[ 362.206942] output fmt YUYV
, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstWaylandSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, framerate=(fraction)120/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)1:4:11:1
```

Comment: Did you test with a simpler pipeline? like `v4l2src ! fakesink`, did you get any error? Did you also try without any specific element between the source and the sink (`v4l2src ! autovideosink`)?

Comment: I edited the question with two additional more simpler pipelines. No Stream has been successfully established with these.